# How to align 3 paragraphs side by side html

Tags: html, alignment, html-table, paragraph

Okay, so I've tried all the possible examples of implementing divs, floats, and in-lines to have all three tables side by side with nothing working. Here is the code I have programmed so far, please show me what I might be doing wrong. I could not figure it out after spending a good few hours trying different ways to input the coding

```
<div align="left;"><div style="width:30%;auto;position;relative;background-color:#131313;border:2px solid #1b463d;"><div style="left;"><img src="http://wallpapershacker.com/wallpaper_3840x2160/clockwork_watches_clocks_time_desktop_1600x1200_hd-wallpaper-455121.jpg" style="max-width:100%;">

<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:#111111;text-align:float:left;justify;font-family:verdana;font-size:10px;color:#636362;"><br>CLOCKWORK DREAMS.</br> This is where the machines rule. Whether it be an entire being augmented with robotics, or humans with mechanical adornaments. Those who embrace Science and obey its principles are welcomed here. >$[zone_1]</div></div>
```

```
<div align="left;"><div style="width:30%;auto;position;relative;background-color:#131313;border:2px solid #1b463d;"><div style="center;"><img src="http://trucosyfondos.com/fondos-de-pantalla/data/media/10/Demon_angel.jpg" style="max-width:100%;">

<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:#111111;text-align:float:left;justify;font-family:georgia;font-size:10px;color:#636362;"><br>TRANSCENDED.</br>Hell and Heaven have an existence, and this is where it dwells. Those who are monsters, saints, or perhaps even a hybrid of each thrive in this part of the world. >$[zone_2]</div></div>
```

```
<div align="left;"><div style="width:30%;auto;position;relative;background-color:#131313;border:2px solid #1b463d;"><div style="right;"><img src="http://orig10.deviantart.net/8658/f/2007/202/9/b/human_reflection_by_yudha3.jpg" style="max-width:100%;">

<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:#111111;text-align:float:left;justify;font-family:sylfaen;font-size:10px;color:#636362;"><br>THE ENIGMATIC</br>What does it mean to be human? The idea of freedom and independance has long been sought for, and here is where those ideals exist. >$[zone_3]</div></div>
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your question? Maybe this link might help: http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

Comment: I'm trying to show the code I used, but it formats it when I do

Comment: you have to select your code and click on this icon: {}

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
Look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/fh2st5nm/2/

html:

```
 <div class="oneThird">
  <img src="http://wallpapershacker.com/wallpaper_3840x2160/clockwork_watches_clocks_time_desktop_1600x1200_hd-wallpaper-455121.jpg" />
  <p>CLOCKWORK DREAMS.<br> This is where the machines rule. Whether it be an entire being augmented with robotics, or humans with mechanical adornaments. Those who embrace Science and obey its principles are welcomed here. >$[zone_1]</p></div>
 <div class="oneThird">
   <img src="http://trucosyfondos.com/fondos-de-pantalla/data/media/10/Demon_angel.jpg" />
   <p>TRANSCENDED.<br>Hell and Heaven have an existence, and this is where it dwells. Those who are monsters, saints, or perhaps even a hybrid of each thrive in this part of the world. >$[zone_2]</p></div>
 <div class="oneThird">
   <img src="http://orig10.deviantart.net/8658/f/2007/202/9/b/human_reflection_by_yudha3.jpg" />
<p>THE ENIGMATIC<br>What does it mean to be human? The idea of freedom and independance has long been sought for, and here is where those ideals exist. >$[zone_3]</p></div>
```

css:

```
.oneThird {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #111;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: sylfaen;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #636362;
  }
 .oneThird img {width: 100%;}
 .oneThird p {padding: 3px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        here you dont need css also you should have one main div with width 100% and its children are have style float=left likebelow

    <div id="maindiv">
            <div class="inline">div 111111111111111111  </div>
            <div class="inline">div 2222222222222222222 </div>
            <div class="inline"> div 33333333333333333333333</div>
       </div>

css..........
.inline{
float:left
}
```

Comment: Don't give bad habits, don't use "style" in dom, even more if you are repeating it. :)